# apache subdomain rewrite to query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file, when I type http://adidas.localhost/ in the URL the 'store' query variable does not get appended, however when I add a single character for example http://adidas.localhost/1 it will work perfectly fine, but not without any characters after the slash, I've tried everything and haven't been able to come up with a solution, thanks.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.localhost$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/?store=%1&uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have any other rule that matches the subdomain homepage ?

Comment: @starkeen No only this file

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.localhost$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/?store=%1&uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```